# How to color highlight text log entries (Apache, Log4J) during terminal viewing

Tags: linux, shell, logging

I'm frequently eye-balling apache and jboss logs on Linux with "less" and "tail -f" and would like to have particular lines that match a string to be highlighted in a color of my choice.  Is there a way to do this?

I am typically connected via ssh from an MS-DOS command window.

Edit:  Preferably, the solution would not modify the log file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have access to a terminal right now, but you can try this,

In Apache config file when you define the `LogFormat`, try using shell color codes. E.g.,

> LogFormat "${START}%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b ${END}" common_color

where

> START="\e[1;34m" # for a blue text, you can use other colors as well
>
> END="\e[0m"

This should work in shell terminals

Comment: I was thinking someone would mention awk or some kind of preprocessor to pipe to less.